# PowerShell Rotate Image Size Issue

Tags: .net, image, winforms, powershell

I am rotating Images using PowerShell. My code looks like this:

```
$path = "C:\img.jpg"
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms"); 
$i = new-object System.Drawing.Bitmap $path
$i.RotateFlip("Rotate90FlipNone")
$i.Save($path,"png")
```

It is rotating correctly, but after rotation the size of the image gets very big. A 1.5MB image grows to between 5MB and 12MB. Does anyone know why this is and how to fix it?

Comment: My guess is that the original image was heavily compressed. Bitmap.Save() doesn't support PNG compression afaik

Comment: I agree that the size increase you see, is because you are decompressing the image as well as rotating. Here is an interesting reference. [How to: Set JPEG Compression Level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882583%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You rotate the image and also do the conversion from JPG to PNG. PNG supports lossless data compression while JPEG is a lossy format with generally smaller output file size. For an experiment you can take some png image instead of jpeg and rotate it - then the size will probably not change or change a little. If you don't want the size to grow you should try to save it like this

```
$i.Save($path,"jpeg")
```

Comment: Thanks for this, using jpeg did the trick. The photo size now gets smaller, which is interesting, but is not a problem as it actually help me.